# How do you find the real solutions to these simultaneous equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

I am looking for all real $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy the following

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}2a + a^2b = b\\ 
2b + b^2c = c\\
2c + c^2a = a\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

I know that $a=b=c = 0$ is the only real solution to the problem I know of but I don't know how to prove it.

I was also given the hint, substitute $a = \tan(x)$.

Comment: Try to get each one in terms of the same variables, so that you have, for example, $c=...$ for all of them. You could alternatively try to find the solution set for any pair, and show that it has no intersection with the solution set for another pair... what sort of class is this for? Context would be helpful.

Comment: $a = \tan t \implies b=\tan 2t.\implies  c = \tan 4t\implies \tan t  = \tan 8 t$

Comment: hmmm... $a = \tan \frac \pi7 \approx 0.48, b = \tan \frac {2\pi}7\approx 1.25,c = \tan \frac {4\pi}7 \approx -4.38$ appears to be a valid solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b = \frac {2a}{1-a^2}$

$a = \tan t$

$b = \tan 2t\\
c = \tan 4t\\
a = \tan 8t$

$tan t = tan 8t\\
t + n\pi = 8t\\
7t = n\pi\\
t = \frac {n}{7} \pi$

$a,b,c = \tan \frac {n\pi}{7}, \tan \frac {2n\pi}{7},\tan \frac {4n\pi}{7}$

Comment: so there is infinite solutions to this unless you restrict the range of t?

Comment: @RossMillikan Why restrict $t$ there is no reason to.  but supposing you do.. then $\tan \frac {4\pi}{7} = \tan \frac {-3\pi}{7}$ and nothing has changed.

Comment: @BenFranks No, there are $7$ solutions,  once $n$ gets past $7$, you cycle through the same solutions.  But if you find a solution that works for $(a,b,c)$ then it will also work for $(b,c,a)$ and $(c,a,b).$  So treating these as equivalent, you could say that there are $3$ solution sets.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer and I thank you for helping me understand this problem so easily. Not sure what I was thinking at the end there, probably because I haven't touched general equations for a few years.

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      \tan y &=& b &=& \dfrac{2a}{1-a^2} \\ 
      \tan z &=& c &=& \dfrac{2b}{1-b^2} \\ 
      \tan x &=& a &=& \dfrac{2c}{1-c^2} \\ 
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      \tan y &=& \tan 2x  \\ 
      \tan z &=& \tan 2y \\ 
      \tan x &=& \tan 2z \\ 
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      y &=& p\pi+2x \\ 
      z &=& q\pi+2y \\ 
      x &=& r\pi+2z \\ 
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  -2 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & -2 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} p\pi \\ q\pi \\ r\pi \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\frac{4}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{1}{7} \\
  -\frac{1}{7} & -\frac{4}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} \\
  -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{1}{7} & -\frac{4}{7}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} p\pi \\ q\pi \\ r\pi \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Your signs are mixed up I reckon. Interesting solution.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Corrected, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Prove and use

$$\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)} = \tan(2x)$$

Comment: Thank you for this identity, I managed to solve it the way Roos Millikan did using this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an algebra problem, let me give a pure algebraic solution without using any trigonometric functions, so that it's accessible to those who haven't learnt them.

Make a variable the subject of each equation like this.

\begin{cases}
b =& \dfrac{2a}{1-a^2} \\ 
c =& \dfrac{2b}{1-b^2} \\
a =& \dfrac{2c}{1-c^2} \tag{S} \label{S}
\end{cases}

Note that each variable can't be equal to $\pm1$.  (We have $2a + a^2 b = b$, so if $a^2 = 1$, $2a = 0$, which is equivalent to $a = 0$, which is a contradiction.)  Thus, writing each variable as a fraction in \eqref{S} is allowed.

Multiply the three equations in \eqref{S}.

\begin{align}
abc &= \frac{8abc}{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2)} \\
abc = 0 \quad &\text{or}\quad (1-a^2)(1-b^2)(1-c^2) = 8
\end{align}

If we have $abc = 0$, meaning that one of them must be zero.  No matter which one we start with (say $a = 0$), we can always use \eqref{S} to deduce that the other two variables are also equal to zero.  (Since $b \stackrel{\eqref{S}}= \dfrac{2a}{1-a^2}$, $b = 0$, and similarly, $c = 0$.)

In the second case, it suffices to find $a$ and $b$.

\begin{align}
1 - \frac{8}{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)} &= c^2 \\
1-b^2 - \frac{8}{1-a^2} &= \frac{4b^2}{1-b^2} \\
1-\frac{4a^2}{(1-a^2)^2} - \frac{8}{1-a^2} &= \frac{16a^2}{(1-a^2)^2-4a^2} \\
\frac{(1-a^2)^2-8(1-a^2)-4a^2}{a^4-2a^2+1} &= \frac{16a^2}{a^4-6a^2+1} \\
\frac{a^4+2a^2-7}{a^4-2a^2+1} &= \frac{16a^2}{a^4-6a^2+1} \\
a^8 - 4a^6 - 18a^4 + 44a^2 - 7 &= 16a^6 - 32a^4 + 16a^2 \\
a^8 - 20a^6 + 14a^4 + 28a^2 - 7 &= 0 \\
(a^2 + 1)(a^6 - 21a^4 + 35a^2 - 7) &= 0 \\
a^6 - 21a^4 + 35a^2 - 7 &= 0 \\
\end{align}

By Eisenstein's criterion with $p = 7$, this polynomial has no rational roots.  We note *temporarily* $a = 1$, $b = -21$, $c = 35$ and $d = -7$ for solving this cubic equation

$$ x^3 - 21x^2 + 35x - 7 = 0. \tag{#}\label{cubic} $$

\begin{align}
\Delta_0 &= b^2-3ac = 336 \\
\Delta_1 &= 2b^3 - 9abc + 27a^d = -12096 \\
\Delta &= -\frac{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}{27a^2} = 200704 > 0, \quad \text{so we have 3 distinct real roots.} \\
C &= \sqrt[3]{\frac12 \left(\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}+\Delta_1\right)} = \sqrt[3]{672\left(-9+i\sqrt{3}\right)} \\
x &= -\frac{1}{3a}\left(b+\omega^n C+\frac{\Delta_0}{\omega^n C}\right),
\end{align}

where $\omega = -\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and $n \in \{0,1,2\}$.

Denote the roots of the cubic equation \eqref{cubic} by $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

[Possible values of $a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-21x%5E2%2B35x-7%3D0) is $\sqrt\alpha$,$\sqrt\beta$, and $\sqrt\gamma$.  By observing the symmetry under cyclic permutation of $a$, $b$ and $c$, we see that the permutations of the three roots of \eqref{cubic} are possible solutions for $a^2$, $b^2$ and $c^2$.

In \eqref{S}, we observe that we can change the sign of each variable $a$, $b$ or $c$.

To conclude, apart from $(a,b,c) = (0,0,0)$, we have *six* solutions to \eqref{S}, by permuting the roots and signs of $\{\pm\sqrt\alpha,\pm\sqrt\beta,\pm\sqrt\gamma\}$.

Comment: See the Wolfram Alpha [**output**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B%7B2a%2Ba%5E2b%3Db,2b%2Bb%5E2c%3Dc,2c%2Bc%5E2a%3Da%7D,%7Ba,b,c%7D%5D)

Comment: @NgChungTak Thanks for spotting out this serious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation implies c>a and c>b.
But the third equation implies b>c and b>a.
Therefore, the given simultaneous equations can only be satisfied by a=0, b=0, and c=0.

Comment: See the other answers.  Actually there's 7 real solutions.